# Run-time user input

Tags: inputfield

A question about run-time data input.

I have a notebook that scrapes data from a web site that presents new data every day on a new web page, e.g.:

```
http://___/nov1.htm
http://___/nov2.htm
http://___/nov3.htm etc.
```

I would like to have my notebook prompt the user for the desired date(s) and then have that date automatically incorporated into the URL name so that the correct file(s) can be fetched using the Import command.  So far I have not found documentation how do to this, and would be very grateful for any suggestions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Old way:  [`Input`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Input.html) and [`InputString`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/InputString.html).  This might be sufficient for you.

New way: [`InputField`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/InputField.html) and [`CreateDialog`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/CreateDialog.html).  See second Basic Example for `CreateDialog`.

There are even newer ways using forms and [`Ask`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Ask.html).  I have never used these so I'll leave the answer to others.  They are targeted at creating web interfaces, but can also be used in the notebook.  They will give you automatic checking (is it a vlid URL?).  Here's the reference: http://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/SettingUpUserInteractions.html